# How can you use a Python @click command decorator in a class method?

Tags: python-3.x, python-3.7, python-click

My Python script has a class named `Command`. I want to call my class' method as a CLI command (something like `python cli-comand.py net get-public-ip`).

I used the Python `click` library, but when I tried to execute it, it throws the error `TypeError: get_public_ip() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'`.

As expected, I am not able to pass `self`. Is there any way to pass arguments into the class method, or any other approach?  `click` is mostly used with functions.

My Python script is below:

**cli-command.py**

```
import click
import urllib.request
from typing import List, AnyStr
from urllib.error import URLError

from ttn_cli.utils.constants import FETCH_PUBLIC_IP_URL


@click.group()
def cli():
    """
    This is the root function of cli module.
    """
    pass


@cli.group()
def net():
    """
    function act as a group which is linked to root cli function.
    """
    pass


class Command:

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    @net.command()  #  <-- click command
    def get_public_ip(self, *args) -> AnyStr:  # I want to use this method as a cli command
        """
        Function used to get public ip of your host.
        args: List of arguments provided
        """
        try:
            ip = urllib.request.urlopen(FETCH_PUBLIC_IP_URL).read().decode(
                "utf-8")
            return ip
        except URLError:
            return "Please check your internet connectivity"


cmd_network = Command()


def main() -> None:
    """
    This is the main function which returns a shell to user as well
    as can run cli commands directly.
    """
    cli()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a late answer to an old question but I hope that somebody might find it useful in future...

You can use two decorators that would help you achieve that:

- `click.pass_context` applied to a group that would give it a context on which you can create an instance of your `Command` class.
- `click.pass_obj` applied to the class' method that would pass that instance as the first argument.

In your example it would look like this:

```
import click

@click.group()
def cli():
    pass

@cli.group()
@click.pass_context
def net(ctx):
    ctx.obj = Command()

class Command:
    @net.command()
    @click.pass_obj
    def get_public_ip(self, *args):
        ...

def main() -> None:
    cli()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**Notes:**

- It assumes that you have some reason for having `main` function because otherwise you could call `cli()` directly in the `if __name__ == "__main__"` block.
- This was tested in click 8.1.3. I don't know in what version were the decorators introduced.